# MS Excel - count number of different days for a given month and year il a list of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In MS Excel, I've a list of different dates in a column 
I'd like to count the number of different days (day month year) in the list for a given year and month

I'd like to have a formula and not using a pivot table

**Sample**

[image]

I found a partial solution

=sumprod(1/count.if(A1:A4;A1:A5))

=sumprod(1/count.if(A6:A17;A6:A17))

But here I've to define the start and end of the month in the selection it doesn't work for the whole column (A:A) or when months are mixed

Comment: I would recommend to investigate the function TEXT to convert a date to month / year and the function COUNTIF, then come back if you get stuck

Comment: already tried id but without success...

Comment: could you share the formulas that you have used?

Answer (score 0):

This Array Formula will work:

```
=COUNT(IF(MONTH(A1:A100)=2,IF(YEAR(A1:A100)=2016,1,0)))
```

make sure to press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** when exiting cell edit mode.

Comment: I think it misses an AND but even with it it doesn't work
Furthermore I have several times the same date in my list. I also tried with sumprod but without success.

Comment: @user5918556 - it's not missing an `AND`. It's an array formula. Be sure to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`. If you have duplicate dates and only want it to count once, then that is certainly more complex. It would have been best to state that in your original question. Can you post a screenshot or embed a sample of your existing data set because I can't help much further without it.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to only count once the duplicate.
I added a sample in the main post

Comment: This gives me 12 when it should give me 5

Comment: @user5918556 - you may need a to make a UDF (via VBA) for this. It's getting the unique values that is tricky. The other option is to perform a `Remove Duplicates` operation on the column first, then the answer in my formula will work perfectly.

Comment: The VBA formula will do it but I'd like to avoid it.
I can't user the remove duplicate since in real use I've many more columns.

Comment: @user5918556 - You can use the `Remove Duplicates` feature on the entire column set by only specify to remove the duplicates from the date column (and ignore the rest). Or you can copy that column to a separate tab to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple formula and change the range for your application :

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A10;A2:A10)>0,1;1;0))
```

- The frequency will count how many time a single date occurs
- the IF will change the frequency into 1 each frequency
- The SUM will sum all your IFs and count how many different date you have

Hope it answered your question,
if you need more info : [office has some info about it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273#bmcount_the_number_of_unique_values_by_)

Comment: This doesn't take in account the specific month and year
In the above sample it fives me 18 if I take the whole column (A:A) when it should give me 3 for january 2016 and 5 for february 2016